# What letter pairs are the most frequent in English written text?

Tags: frequency-analysis

Just as there is a common frequency of single letter occurrences which is very easy to find, is there a list of the most common letter pairs in English?  I’m looking for a concrete list.

Comment: Do you mean *any* letter pair (e.g. pa, ai, ir in pair)? Pairs that include letters from two different words (e.g. rp in *letter pair*)?

Comment: see here: http://norvig.com/mayzner.html

Comment: What corpus would you consider relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Hardly a question about English usage but it has its charms. Here are the first 20 pairs from a list of a few hundred that I  derived from the complete *Mathematica Dictionary* (see [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)) of over 90K words. I add that this is a general purpose dictionary and that any list of words from any other dictionary could be used. The frequency of each letter pair is given as a percentage of all dictionary words in which the pair occurs.

Do you need any more?

{in, 19}, {er, 18}, {es, 16}, {ng, 12}, {ti,
12}, {re, 11}, {te, 11}, {ed, 11}, {on, 10}, {at,
10}, {st, 9.7}, {an, 9.1}, {en, 8.9}, {le, 8.6}, {ri,
7.9}, {ra, 7.8}, {al, 7.8}, {li, 7.6}, {ar, 7.5}, {is,
7.0}

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Just some rough estimate of what letter pairs are more frequent than others in some arbitrary collection of English words.

Comment: My effort only deals with one dictionary. It could deal with a large body of typical prose but I did not know where to find such representative material. I could have analysed the bible or the text of a few novels, but these too would have been arbitrary choices on my part. Best wait to see if anyone else comes up with a better list before accepting my answer.